# Using TVP with codeigniter framework & MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I cannot find any documentation on using TVP with codeigniter & MSSQL, and need to call a stored procedure with a list of int as a single parameter.

```sql
-- UDTT
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TypeInteger] AS TABLE (
    [Id] INT NULL);

-- Stored Procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE spDoStuff
    @Ids dbo.TypeInteger READONLY
AS ...
```

```php
// Make array of int
$int_array = array(1, 2, 3);

// Create a TVP input array, per documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/use-table-valued-parameters?view=sql-server-ver16
$tvpType = 'TypeInteger';
$tvpInput = array($tvpType => $int_array);

// Run the query & iterate results
$sql = "spDoStuff ?";
$query = $tsdb->query($sql, $tvpInput); // <-- error here: Array to string conversion /project_folder/ci_2.2.6_sys/database/DB_driver.php 605

foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{ ... }
```

Thanks

Comment: The examples in [Use table-valued parameters (PHP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/use-table-valued-parameters) don't include `dbo.` when setting `$tvpType`... significant?

Comment: Unfortunately makes no difference.  Cheers @AlwaysLearning

Answer (score 0):

I've bypassed codeigniter and followed [Microsoft's guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/use-table-valued-parameters?view=sql-server-ver16), php now looks like this:

```php
/* Specify the server and connection string attributes. */
$serverName = "localhost";

/* Get UID and PWD from application-specific files.  */
$uid = "username";//file_get_contents("C:\AppData\uid.txt");
$pwd = "password";//file_get_contents("C:\AppData\pwd.txt");
$connectionInfo = array(
    "UID" => $uid,
    "PWD" => $pwd,
    "Database" => "databaseName"
);

/* Connect using SQL Server Authentication. */
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
if ($conn === false) {
    echo "Unable to connect.</br>";
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

/* Set the parameters. */
$int_array = array(1, 2, 3);
$tvpType = 'TypeInteger';
$tvpInput = array($tvpType => $int_array);

$params = array(array($tvpInput, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_TABLE, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_TABLE));

/* Query SQL Server. */
$tsql = "{call spDoStuff(?)}";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, $params);
if ($stmt === false) {
    echo "Error in executing query.</br>";
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}        
        
/* Retrieve each row as an associative array and display the results.*/  
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))  
{  
    echo $row['LastName'].", ".$row['FirstName']."\n";
}  

/* Free statement and connection resources. */
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn);
```

Now $row can be iterated.